# How can I use content.document with multiprocessCompatible on Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to develop an Firefox Extention, and I want to get current web page tags by this extension with this code :

```
var bodyTag = content.document.getElementsByTagName("body");
```

but if I set

```
<em:multiprocessCompatible>false</em:multiprocessCompatible>
```

in install.rdf, this extension works well. But this is not supported in other versions of firefox.
When I set

```
 <em:multiprocessCompatible>true</em:multiprocessCompatible>
```

in install.rdf, it doesn't work at all.

So, what should I do or what code should I replace with content.document in JavaScript?

Comment: can you switch to using JPM or Web Extensions - the two newer add-on SDK's

Comment: I test code like this "var doc =  e.target.defaultView.document; or 
 var doc =gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentDocument; or  var doc = gBrowser.browsers[0].contentDocument;" but they don't work.

Comment: Have you read [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Working_with_multiprocess_Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "**You can't**".

[Multiprocess Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Working_with_multiprocess_Firefox) separates chrome code and content into separate processes. To function with `<em:multiprocessCompatible>true</em:multiprocessCompatible>` requires that you are not doing things like what you describe (trying to access page content from your chrome code). Setting that option explicitly turns off the [compatibility shims](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/Limitations_of_chrome_scripts#Compatibility_shims) which would make it possible, in a limited fashion, to access page content using that method on multiprocess Firefox.

You will need to [adapt to using a content script/worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Working_with_multiprocess_Firefox#Adapting_to_Multiple_Processes) to access page content.  You will then use the [Message Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Working_with_multiprocess_Firefox#Using_the_Message_Manager) to pass messages from your content script/page script/frame script. Without significantly more information from you (and showing us much more code) it would be well beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer to explain all possible ways for you to access page content.

### Start Using [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) NOW

Rather than try to refactor/rewrite your legacy extension code to remain functional with multiprocess Firefox, you should transition it to a WebExtension. [Mozilla has announced](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/11/23/add-ons-in-2017/) [emphasis mine]:

> ***By the end of 2017***, and with the release of [Firefox 57](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar), **we’ll move to WebExtensions exclusively, and will stop loading any other extension types on desktop**. To help ensure any new extensions work beyond the end of 2017, [AMO will stop accepting any new extensions](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Add-ons/2017#Firefox_53) for signing that are not WebExtensions in [Firefox 53](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar). Throughout the year we’ll expand the set of APIs available, add capabilities to Firefox that don’t yet exist in other browsers, and put more WebExtensions in front of users.